# ahk sendinput works on button click but not on ^Down

Tags: autohotkey

Using Autohotkey, can anyone explain why this isnt working?

```
    ^Down::
        Gosub, Close
    return

    Close:
        MsgBox CLOOOOSE
        GuiControlGet, editText,, MyEdit
        WinMinimize TemplateEngine
        SendInput, {raw}%editText%
        MsgBox CLOOOOSE
    return
```

When I use a button

```
Gui, Add, Button, gClose x30 y44, Close
```

This works and the SendInput does what I want.

If I use ^Down (CTRL + Arrow Down) the SendInput doesnt do anything

Ive also tried this

```
^Down::
Close:
    MsgBox CLOOOOSE
    GuiControlGet, editText,, MyEdit
    WinMinimize TemplateEngine
    SendInput, {raw}%editText%
    MsgBox CLOOOOSE
 return
```

Why does the button click and hotkey end up with different results, even though they call the same actions?
Please help

Comment: I works like a charm on AutoHotKey_L. I Suggest to try another Gosub Label as "Close" is a reserved word (but then again it worked with the label "close" on Win7 + AHK_L)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the SendInput doesnt work on the ^Down, it does when I use a button to goto the Close label.

Comment: I suggest that you first put a "dummy" MsgBox visual alert in the ^Down:: hotkey part, just to check to see that this shortcut fires correctly. As said before, the ^Down Gosub, Close: works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What I tested was:

```
^Down::
    MsgBox, Cntrl down
    Gosub, Close
    MsgBox, Back to Cntrl Down
return

Close:
    editText=My Message
    MsgBox, CLOSE Subroutine
    SendInput, {raw}%editText%
return
```

And it shows all the MsgBox alerts and places My Message in Notepad. Not sure what I can do differently. Is the routine is fired correctly on ^Down, but behaves differently?

Comment: The routine fires, but I have a WinMinimize that your routine doesnt include.  with the winminimize the sendinput isnt doing what I expect

Comment: Question, why did you include a winMinimize? What are you trying to achieve? Is TemplateEngine the exact window name or did you define the SetTitleMatchMode = 2 elsewhere? Have you checked the content of your variables after the GuiControlGet? and might the MsgBox have messed-up your window focus? Just a few questions.